# Download artifact fail due to exception

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

In one of our build we publish the artifact into a shared folder. And in the release who triggered by the build, we have some environment that enable download artifact by default. But the downloading is always fail and said:

### [error]Downloading artifacts failed: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.$Parameter name: fileName$   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Windows.Implementation.FileSystemDirectory.GetFileReader(String fileName)

Because it is the default behavior of the environment, we don't know which part is wrong. And on the agent machine, the release folder was created with a sub folder named by the build. But nothing inside the sub folder.
We try to make the build and release use the same agent and publish the build artifact onto this agent machine. But the downloading is fail with the same error.

[image]

[Update] We are using VSTS. And the published artifact can be downloaded from the shared folder.

Comment: If you go to the build can you download and access the artifacts?

Comment: Which server are you using? Visual Studio Team Service or On-premise TFS Server?

Comment: Hi @Max, did you solve this one?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT this is happening following the last release of RM (RM for VS 2015), we're running on-premise

Answer (score 3):

Can you please check if length of downloading complete file path is exceeding windows allowable limit, which should be 256?